# Bases of a linear trasformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Why in a linear trasformation ( represented by a matrix) we **just** need to know how a base is mapped by the function to know the overal behavior of the function ?

Comment: If I had to put it shortly, I'd say it is because of how a linear transformation is defined. It satisfies $T(\vec v_1+\vec v_2)=T(\vec v_1)+T(\vec v_2)$ and $T(\alpha \vec v)=\alpha T(\vec v)$, and once you know how the basis is mapped, this uniquely determines the transformations using those two rules (as all vectors are some linear combination of the basis vectors).

Comment: Yes, it's precisely the linearity that lets you move from the basis the the general element: $T(\sum_i a_i\mathbf{x}_i) = \sum_i a_iT(\mathbf{x}_i)$. Without that, you have nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:V \to W$ be a linear map and $b_1,....,b_n$ be a basis of V.

If we know $f(b_j)=c_j$ for $j=1,...,n$, then we know $f(v)$ for each $v \in V$:

there are uniquely determined scalars $t_1,...,t_n$ with $v=t_1b_1+...+t_nb_n$. By linearity:

$f(v)=t_1c_1+...+t_nc_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$. This is the same as saying that for every $v$ in $V$, we can find unique coefficients $\alpha_i$ such that
$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i
$$
Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation. If we know what happens to the basis elements, then we know what happens to $v$ because $T$ is *linear*.  In particular,
$$
T(v) = T\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i v_i \right) = 
\sum_{i=1}^n T(\alpha_i v_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i T(v_i)
$$
and we already know what $T(v_i)$ is for $i = 1,\dots,n$.

Answer (score 0):

To know what a linear transformation is, we only need to know what it does to a basis. To see that this is true, we need to remember the fundamental properties of linear transformations and bases: linear transformations distribute nicely over linear combinations, and any vector can be written as a linear combination of the vectors of a basis. Let $T$ be our linear transformation and $\mathscr{B} = \{b_1, \dots, b_k\}$ be our basis that we have in mind. We suppose that we know $T(b_i)$ for all $i = 1, \dots k$. Then for any $x$ in the domain of $T$, we have for some scalars $c_1, \dots c_k$

$$ x = c_1 b_1 + \cdots + c_k b_k .$$

Then

$$ T(x) = T(c_1 b_1 + \cdots + c_k b_k) = T(c_1 b_1) + \cdots + T(c_k b_k) = c_1 T(b_1) + \cdots c_k T(b_k) .$$

We know $c_1, \dots, c_k$ and $T(b_1), \dots, T(b_k)$, so we know $T(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to linearty the knowledge of the images of the base vectors under the linear transform suffices:
$$
A x 
= A \left(\sum_i x_i b_i\right) 
= \sum_i A \left(x_i b_i\right) 
= \sum_i x_i \left(A b_i\right) 
$$